# Heroku postgres populate file permission denied

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I Get this error message when I try to give my postgres heroku backend an sql file to init the database.
I've tried to change permissions of the file and give it all read and write. I don't know what the problem is.
I suspect it's postgres/sql related but I don't know what to do.

```
simao@simao-kde-neon:~/Desktop/t1g1$ heroku pg:psql postgresql-colorful-03183 -a differ-backend < init.sql 
--> Connecting to postgresql-colorful-03183
could not read from input file: Permission denied
 ▸    psql exited with code 1
```

Comment: To any lost soul who has a similar problem. Even though I had previously moved it to the temp folder and still nothing when I moved the file to the desktop it miraculously worked.a

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the Heroku pg utilities use your own local installation of postgres under the hood. Looking at that error, it seems like whichever user runs `psql` locally doesn't have permissions for `init.sql`. Try `chmod` on the sql file to make sure that the correct user has permission to read the file.

Comment: How do I see which user runs psql? I only have the 'simao' user that is the root.
I also changed the file permissions to allow all users and nothing changed `chmod 777 init.sql`